# running a while loop in parallel

Tags: rust

We have a while loop that searches for a string in hundred of tables in several hundred databases. We don't need to find the exact location of the string, but just want to know if it exists somewhere.

In each iteration we pick a table at random and search for the string in that table

After every 500 iteration, if the string is not already found, we pop one character from the end of the string and search for the remaining string, so and so forth.

```
let mut i = 1;
let mut str_not_found = true;
while str_not_found {
  if i % 500 == 0{
    search_str.pop()
  }
  //search for string in the table . if it exists set str_not_found to false
}
```

This works, but we want to parallelize in it. What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: use a threadpool, push 500 table tasks, run it in parallel the 500 in N by N threads  batches (?). If it is io-bound (as it should because they are databases) use tokio, otherwise rayon probably.

Answer (score 0):

**Cargo.toml**

```
[dependencies]
rand = "0.8.5"
crossbeam-channel = "0.5.4"
crossbeam-utils = "0.8.8"
```

**main.rs**

```rs
use rand::Rng;
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use crossbeam_channel::bounded;
use crossbeam_utils::thread as cthread;

fn main() {
    let workers = 15;
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let (sx, rx) = bounded(workers);
    let mut search_str = String::from("one");
    let found = Arc::new(Mutex::new(false));

    println!("FOUND {:?}", *found.lock().unwrap());

    cthread::scope(|s| {
        let mut idx: u32 = 0;

        while !*found.lock().unwrap() && search_str.len() > 0 {
            sx.send(search_str.clone()).unwrap();
            let r1 = rx.clone();
            let _sleep = rng.gen_range(0..30);

            s.spawn({
                let f = Arc::clone(&found);
                move |_| {
                    thread::sleep(Duration::from_secs(_sleep + 1));
                    // temporary found the string under 45 thread/worker
                    if idx == 45 {
                        let mut tmp = f.lock().unwrap();
                        *tmp = true;
                    }

                    println!("Worker: {:?}, Sleeped: {:?}, Searched : {:?}", idx, _sleep, r1.recv().unwrap());
                }
            });

            if idx > 0 && idx % 15 == 0 {
                search_str.pop();
            }

            idx += 1;
        }
    }).unwrap();

    println!("FOUND {:?}", *found.lock().unwrap());

    println!("Bye!");
}
```